# Why does @Url.Action not output Index when you specify Index as the action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

Why does @Url.Action not output Index when you specify Index as the action?

I am trying to output a URL using razor @Url.Action("Index", "Admin"), but the out is http://localhost/Admin. The result is that the routing thinks /Admin is a category and is caught by the wrong route.

The routes I am using are

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");


        routes.MapRoute(
            null,
            "Page{page}",
            new { Controller = "Photo", action="List" , category = (string)null },
            new { page = @"\d+" }
        );


        routes.MapRoute(
            null,
            "{category}",
            new { Controller = "Photo", action = "List", page=1 }
        );


        routes.MapRoute(
            null,
            "{category}/Page{page}",
            new { Controller = "Photo", action = "List"},
            new { page = @"\d+" }
        );


        // Default MVC route (fallback)
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "App", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(null, "{controller}/{action}");
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this is because of your default route

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "App", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

when `action url` is created it will see your `default` route so your route will be `Admin/{action}` because your action is same as `default` action so it will ignore writing it in url and if you still want to show `index` change the order of your routes to

```
routes.MapRoute(null, "{controller}/{action}");


 routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "App", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by adding two new routes.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");


        routes.MapRoute(
            "AdminIndex",                                           // Route name
            "Admin",                            // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index" }  // Parameter defaults
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Admin",                                           // Route name
            "Admin/Page{page}",                            // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index" }  // Parameter defaults
        );


        routes.MapRoute(
            null,
            "Page{page}",
            new { Controller = "Photo", action="List" , category = (string)null },
            new { page = @"\d+" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            null,
            "{category}",
            new { Controller = "Photo", action = "List", page=1 }
        );


        routes.MapRoute(
            null,
            "{category}/Page{page}",
            new { Controller = "Photo", action = "List"},
            new { page = @"\d+" }
        );


        //Default MVC route(fallback)
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "App", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(null, "{controller}/{action}");
    }
```